# Angular "Ngx-Captcha" gives an error when run "ng build myAppName --prod" but without --prod is ok

Tags: angular

I use Ngx-Captcha(version 9.0.1) component in my Angular 7 project but when i build my project with **--prod** it gives this error:
**ERROR in : Directive BaseReCaptchaComponent in ./node_modules/ngx-captcha/ngx-captcha.d.ts has no selector, please add it!**

Answer (score 1):

This error was because of version of ngx-captcha that i used(my angular project version is 7) and when i use 8.0.1 version my problem fixed.